# Parent / Child hierarchy with indentation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a parent/child hierarchy with the children identified by an indent. The parent value here is "Total debt to EBITDA". End goal is a formula in column B that checks for an indent in column C and if there is an indent returns the parent value "total debt to EBITDA."

It would ideally look like cell B3.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which "parent value"? Please add a better screenshot for your spreadsheet and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If the indent is because of spaces added in front then testing if the left 1 is a space should do it.  But if the indent is done through formatting then a formula will not be able to do this.  Formula do not "see" formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in the top row next to the first parent row, then drag down to the bottom of the list.

```
=IF(TRIM(B2)<>B2,A1,B2)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!